# How to assign a Closed item to a Past Sprint

Tags: azure-devops

Is it possible to assign a Closed item to a Past Sprint? If so, then how?

After reorganizing our production support process, I created Past Sprints with the hope of charting velocity history.
The problem is that I can't figure out how to move Closed items into newly created Past Sprints.